# i am doing a resourcechange listner as when we publish any content framents then this error is coming

Tags: aem

29.01.2024 16:01:24.805 *ERROR* [Background Update RE-Vintage.core (619)] RE-Vintage.core bundle RE-Vintage.core:0.0.1.SNAPSHOT (619)General problem with descriptor entry '/OSGI-INF/com.re.vintage.core.listeners.CfPublishListener.xml' (org.xml.sax.SAXException: Exception during parsing
org.xml.sax.SAXException: Missing bundle entry resource.paths=content/dam/reown/content-fragments)
org.xml.sax.SAXException: Exception during parsing
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.xml.XmlHandler.startElement(XmlHandler.java:428) [org.apache.felix.scr:2.1.20]
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:510)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:183)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:351)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2710)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:534)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1216)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:635)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:324)
at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:197) [org.apache.sling.xss:2.2.12]
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.loadDescriptor(BundleComponentActivator.java:444) [org.apache.felix.scr:2.1.20]
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.initialize(BundleComponentActivator.java:328) [org.apache.felix.scr:2.1.20]
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.(BundleComponentActivator.java:263) [org.apache.felix.scr:2.1.20]
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.loadComponents(Activator.java:551) [org.apache.felix.scr:2.1.20]
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.access$200(Activator.java:69) [org.apache.felix.scr:2.1.20]
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator$ScrExtension.start(Activator.java:424) [org.apache.felix.scr:2.1.20]
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.AbstractExtender.createExtension(AbstractExtender.java:196) [org.apache.felix.scr:2.1.20]
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.AbstractExtender.modifiedBundle(AbstractExtender.java:169) [org.apache.felix.scr:2.1.20]
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.AbstractExtender.modifiedBundle(AbstractExtender.java:49) [org.apache.felix.scr:2.1.20]
at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:488)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:420)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:232)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:450)
at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.invokeBundleListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:915)
at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:834)
at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:516)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4817)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2336)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998)
at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.core.BaseUpdateInstallHelper.run(BaseUpdateInstallHelper.java:198) [org.apache.felix.webconsole:4.6.2]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Missing bundle entry resource.paths=content/dam/reown/content-fragments
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.xml.XmlHandler.readPropertiesEntry(XmlHandler.java:519) [org.apache.felix.scr:2.1.20]
at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.xml.XmlHandler.startElement(XmlHandler.java:280) [org.apache.felix.scr:2.1.20]
... 35 common frames omitted

solve this error as this is getting me into null state